# How to create objects in a function outside of main?

Tags: c++, class, function, oop, object

Everything runs fine, but my problem is that my main function is too long. Is there a way to create the battle scene outside of the main function? I have tried this, but if i put the battle scene-lets say "Battle()"-In a header file or something, then my objects create an error. Is there any way to make the objects i declare in main work outside the main function. Maybe using pointers or something??

```
 int main()
    {
        Hero Me(100,20,30,40);//Created using overloaded constructor
        Monster m(100,16,18,20);//creates a monster object and uses overloaded constructor to initialize

    cout << "\nAttacking!\n";

//I want this part to be in a function called Battle() outside of main
    while ((Me.getHp() > 0) && (m.getHp() > 0))//Generates error if object not declared in main
    {   
        cout << "\nYour hp is: " << Me.getHp() << endl;
        cout << "The enemy's hp is: "<< m.getHp() << endl;
        cout << "\nThe monster has attacked you!\n";
        cout << "You received " << m.getAttack() << " damage;" << endl;
        Me.damageTaken(m.getAttack());//Me.setHp(Me.getHp() - m.getAttack());//Me.setHp(m.getStrength());
        if(Me.getHp() > 0)//Check if still alive
        {
            cout << "\nYour hp is now: " << Me.getHp() << endl;
            //cout << "Enemy hp is: "<< m.getHp() << endl;
            cout << "\nNow you attacked!\nYou have dealt "<< Me.getAttack() << " Damage" << endl;
            m.damageTaken(Me.getAttack());//m.setHp(m.getHp() - Me.getAttack());//m.setHp(Me.getAttack());

            if(m.getHp() > 0)//Check if still alive
            {
                cout << "Enemy hp is now: " << m.getHp() << endl;
                cout << "\nAttacking again!\n";
            }
        }

    } 
        if ((Me.getHp() > 0) && (m.getHp() <= 0))
                cout <<"\nCongratulations! You killed the enemy!" << endl;

        else if ((Me.getHp() <= 0) && (m.getHp() > 0))
                cout << "You have died!" << endl;




    cin.sync();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Heres the rest if the code:

```
//Hero.h
class Hero:
    public Character
{
public:
    Hero();
    Hero(int, int, int, int);
    ~Hero();

};

//Hero.cpp
Hero::Hero(int newHp, int newLevel, int newAttack, int newDef)
    : Character(newHp, newLevel, newAttack, newDef)
{
    cout << "Hero created using Overloaded function!\n";
    hp = newHp;
    cout << "Hp is: "<< hp << endl;
    level = newLevel;
    cout << "level is: " << level << endl;
    attack = newAttack;
    cout << "Attack is: " << attack << endl;
    defense = newDef;
    cout << "Defense is: " << defense << endl;
    // logging goes here
    // note that you don't need HeroLevel etc. at all any more, just use level
}

Hero::~Hero()
{
    cout << "Hero destroyed!\n";
}


//Monster.h
class Monster:
    public Character //Hero
{
public:
    Monster();
    Monster(int, int, int, int); //explicit
        //:Character(){};
    //Monster(int);
    ~Monster();
};

//Monster.cpp
Monster::Monster(int newHp, int newLevel, int newAttack, int newDef)
    //: hp(newHp), level(newLevel), attack(newAttack), defense(newDef)//initialize list
{
    cout << "Monster created using Overloaded function!\n";
    hp = newHp;
    cout << "Hp is: "<< hp << endl;
    level = newLevel;
    cout << "level is: " << level << endl;
    attack = newAttack;
    cout << "Attack is: " << attack << endl;
    defense = newDef;
    cout << "Defense is: " << defense << endl;
}

Monster::~Monster()
{
    cout << "\nMonster Destroyed";
}

//Character.h
class Character
{

protected://not private, so derived class can use it
    int level;
    int hp;
    int attack;
    int defense;
    Character(); // zero everything by default
    Character(int); // randomly generate everything
    Character(int, int, int, int); // populate explicitly
    ~Character();
public:
    int getAttack() const { return attack; }
    int getDefense() const { return defense; }
    int getHp() const { return hp; }
    int getlevel() const { return level; }

    void setAttack(int);
    void setDefense(int);
    void setStrength(int);
    void setHp(int);
    void setlevel(int);
    void damageTaken(int);

//Character.cpp
Character::Character() : level(0), hp(0), attack(0), defense(0) {}

Character::Character(int hit, int lvl, int att, int def)
 : level(lvl), hp(hit), attack(att), defense(def){}


Character::~Character()
{
    cout << "Character has been destroyed!\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do what you're trying.  If you show us your attempt, it will help.  It's probably easier to correct where you're going wrong than to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: I have tried many different ways, and ittl be wayy too much code to put. I have tried to make the objects before the main as global objects, i tried puttin them in different files and putting the protype in a header, and i even tried making them static. Nothing works!

Comment: I am very sure this can be reduced to a much smaller code example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is somewhat unclear. It is best to show your failed attempts along with the errors you encountered.

Why not just make a member function, "Battle(Character& opponent)" off of Character and implement the fight code there. You could boil it down to something like `while (!isOver()) { doCombatFrame(opponent); }; cout << "Winner is: " << (opponent.isDead()) ? "me" : "the enemy" << endl;` and implement the loop part inside doCombatFrame(), another new member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it three ways:

1. Return copies. This is probably the preferred way, and simplest for simple objects.

   Example of such a function:

   ```
   Hero create_hero()
   {
       Hero hero{...};

       // Other stuff

       return hero;
   }
   ```
2. Return references. The big caveat here is that you can't return references to local variables, you have to return references to data stored elsewhere (e.g. in a vector).
3. Return pointers. This has the same caveat as number 2, returning a pointer to a local variable with e.g. `return &some_local_var;` is a bad idea.

   Example of such a function:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<Hero> create_hero()
   {
       auto hero = std::unique_ptr<Hero>(new Hero{...});

       // other stuff

       // remember that `hero` is a pointer, so the `->` operator has to be used
       // when dereferencing the variable
       // e.g. `hero->some_function()`

       return hero;
   }
   ```

For point number 1, if you have any kind of complex object, you should know about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

For point number 3, I recommend using smart pointers such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), as shown in my example.

Comment: I haven't learned pointers yet, but this is very clear! thank you very much! And by the way, do u have any recommendations of books or sites where i can learn pointers and referencing?